# Display specific results mysql

Tags: mysql

I have the following table

```
ID Name  Progress     Date
------------------------------
1  A1    First Stage  1/1/2013
2  A1    Second Stage 1/2/2013
3  A2    First Stage  1/1/2013
4  A2    Second stage 1/2/2013
5  A3    First Stage  1/2/2013
6  A1    Closed       1/5/2013
```

I would like to display the stage of each name except the one that is ultimately closed.
For example the output of this should be

```
ID Name  Progress     Date
------------------------------
3  A2    First Stage  1/1/2013
4  A2    Second stage 1/2/2013
5  A3    First Stage  1/2/2013
```

Not A1 as A1 is ultimately Closed.

My query display `Select * from table where Progress not like 'Closed'` obviously displays all the results except that row.

Thanks

Comment: Just a little question, why do you use `like`? A simple `=` is enough... you are not comparing patterns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a subquery to filter all the names that you want to exclude:

```
select distinct name from table where progress = 'Closed'
```

Now, use it in your query:

```
select *
from table
where name not in (select distinct name from table where progress = 'Closed');
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: @Ankur Is your table (more exactly, are the fields in your table) indexed? As a thumb rule, if you need to perform searches or filters on a column, that column should be indexed. I sugest an index on both `name` and `progress` columns.

Comment: thanks.. that column wasn't indexed. Let me index it and check.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT x.* 
  FROM my_table x 
  LEFT 
  JOIN my_table y 
    ON y.name= x.name 
   AND y.progress = 'closed' 
 WHERE y.id IS NULL;
```

Comment: (but NOT EXISTS may be quicker)